# Lookup function error in SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services

When i am creating SSRS report getting error like" the value expression for the text box "" has a scope parameter that is not valid a lookup function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a **LOOKUP** function in an expression that is using an incorrect value for the **dataset** score.

In this example, **Product"** is the **scope**.

```
=Lookup(Fields!SaleProdId.Value, Fields!ProductID.Value,  Fields!Name.Value, "Product")
```

Since it doesn't give the text box name, the expression with the Lookup must be in some other object.